# how to remove spaces from algorithm and align nicely algorithm

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, algorithms

I want to remove the spaces between the "and" and the if clauses in the following code:

```
  \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
  \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

   \usepackage{cite}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}

 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.1cm}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Technique}
\begin{algorithmic}
 \begin{algorithm}
  \caption{SurroundednessPattern}

    \FORALL{methodTrace in methodTraceList}   

 \IF {$!$methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
  $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement)
 } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T
 \ELSIF {$!$methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
  $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement)
 } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=N
 \ENDIF 

 \IF {methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
  $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement)
} \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T
 \ELSIF {methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
  $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement)
 } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=N
\ENDIF 
\ENDFOR 



 \FORALL{methodTrace in methodTraceList}   

 \IF {$!$methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
  $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AtLeast1T(methodtrace.Requirement) 
  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AtLeast1T(methodtrace.Requirement)
 } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T
 \ELSIF {$!$methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
  $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
  \AND (!methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
  \OR !methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement))
 } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=N
 \ENDIF 

 \IF {methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
  $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 

  \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AtLeast1T(methodtrace.Requirement)
  } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T

 \ENDIF 
 \ENDFOR 

\end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us not only a piece of code, but a/some compilable minimal working example(s) reproducing your problems.

Comment: my code is compilable I have tried it

Comment: I mean that **the code you show here** is compilable, i.e. it has a document class, and begin with `\begin{document}` and end with `\end{document}` and also states the packages you used. Read more [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: i have changed it

Comment: i've removed the `align` tag, which is specific to the `align` environment in `amsmath` and replaced it by `horizontal-alignment` which covers the text situation described here.

Comment: @user3406764 your example is still not compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's essentially impossible to typeset that piece of text in two-column mode, because of the very long identifiers.

I suggest to use `algorithm*` for typesetting it in single-column format and to use `\raggedright`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}
\caption{SurroundednessPattern}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\raggedright
    \FORALL{methodTrace in methodTraceList}   

    \IF {$!$methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
        $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement)
    } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T

    \ENDIF 

    \IF {methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
        $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement)
    } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T
    \ELSIF {methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
        $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement)
    } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=N
    \ENDIF 
    \ENDFOR 



    \FORALL{methodTrace in methodTraceList}   

    \IF {$!$methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
        $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AtLeast1T(methodtrace.Requirement) 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AtLeast1T(methodtrace.Requirement)
    } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T
    \ELSIF {$!$methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
        $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
        \AND (!methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement) 
        \OR !methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllNs(methodtrace.Requirement))
    } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=N
    \ENDIF 

    \IF {methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
        $!$methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 

        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AtLeast1T(methodtrace.Requirement)
    } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=T

    \ENDIF 
    \ENDFOR 

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Modifying the code to have `algorithm` instead of `algorithm*` you get overfull boxes because some of the identifiers simply cannot fit a line.

[image]